# Problem with connecting to FIREBASE ASSISTANT: The error message states something that is not true

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, firebase-assistant

When I want to connect to Firebase Assistant from Android Studio, I get the following error:
*A config file "...\modules\app\google-services.json" was found, but it indicates a project ID "xyz-18577" that you don't appear to have access to. Request access or delete the file in order to proceed with the connection process.*

I verified in the json file, and it **does not indicate the project with id "xyz-18577"**. There is another project ID, the ID of the project I want to connect to in firebase. The project with the "xyz-18577" does not exist anymore because I deleted it, and created a new one, hoping that this will solve my problem.

- I reconnected to firebase
- I created a new project in firebase, and deleted the old one (with id xyz-18577)
- I downloaded the google-services.json
- I deleted the existing google-services.json, and I moved the new one in the app folder.
- Clean, rebuild, build, reboot, I did everyhting.

What else can I do?

Comment: It looks like your project was deleted correctly (which explains why you don't have access to it anymore), but Android Studio is still finding a reference to the file in a `google-services.json` file on your local disk. I recommend searching your disk for `google-services.json` files and getting rid of any that refer to the deleted project. For a smoother experience, I'd also recommend following the instructions here to set up Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I setup my project based on that description. And I searched for all the google-services.json, because I found this instruction in an answer of some related question. But it still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry to hear that this is still not working for you. In that case, did you try the manual setup that I linked to?